# How to add a floating action button to checkout items selected from a recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button

I created a Fragment to let users select multiple items from a recycler view. And I wanted to add a floating button to let users check out the items which they have selected. But when I add my floating action button on the layout after recycler view it wasn't able to display because the card view fills all the space and I cannot see my FAB(Floating Action button)

I have added a floating action button after recycler view on a linear layout please check the layout resource below

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/fui_bgGoogle"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvSelectItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add floating action button outside from `recyclerView` add long clickListnere which adds value in `fab`

Comment: i use a frame layout and add a reycler view and  a floating action button.The floating action button works.what i want is when i clicked the floating action button i want to pass all the items which have been selected from the recycler view.If possible could you give an example source code

Comment: how can you select the items? please share the code.